# Can't run Chakra UI with Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, chakra-ui

I was looking the [Chakra UI](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui) installation with Next.js 13 from the attached link and I believe did it completely.

However, when I saved my file afterwards, I noticed that the automatic page did not refresh and I encountered a hydration error in places. The error code seen in the console is as follows:

[image]

`layout.tsx` file in below,

```
import './globals.css'
import {Inter} from 'next/font/google'
import Providers from "@/app/chakra-provider";

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
        <html lang="en">
            <Providers>
                {children}
            </Providers>
        </html>
  )
}
```

`provider.tsx`

```
'use client'

import { CacheProvider } from '@chakra-ui/next-js'
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'

export default function Providers({
    children
    }: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {
    return (
        <CacheProvider>
            <ChakraProvider>
                {children}
            </ChakraProvider>
        </CacheProvider>
    )
}
```

I was browsing about this on Stack Overflow, and someone mentioned that he experienced this after replacing the
`<body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>` line
with just `{children}`. I am having a similar problem right now.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76584445/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acutally it was not an issue. it is because of you are using tailwind which reseting the css.

Just add this below code in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

```js
corePlugins: {
  preflight: false,
}
```

For more details: [Solution issue](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight)

Comment: Holy cow I was looking everywhere for a fix. This actually fixed my MDX rendering - using the contentlayer framework. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The top-most layout is called the Root Layout. This required layout is shared across all pages in an application. Root layouts must contain html and body tags.

After some searching I think this maybe the problem
So make sure body tag is present in top-level of the app after html

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

### Another Solution #2

Found the solution here https://storybook.js.org/blog/integrate-nextjs-and-storybook-automatically/ under next/navigation

```
export const Example = {
  parameters: {
    nextjs: {
      appDirectory: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I tried to do it exactly as described in the ChakraUI document (app directiory content at https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started) . I also tried placing provider outside the html tag, but the similar problem persists. The source below does not seem to be related to the problem I am experiencing. Thanks for your time and help though!